# reactJS and getting value in rendered input box

Tags: reactjs

I have a reactJS application which looks up a barcode from a service.  If the barcode is not found on the service, I render an error message to the user and I also render an input box and a button and I prompt the user to manually enter a barcode.  This is the code I am executing:

```
import React from 'react';
import '../styles/app.css';

class Lookupbarcode extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);  
    this.state = {
        barcode: '',
    };
} 

barcodeLookup(passedBarcode) {
    let currentComponent = this;

    let url = "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/http://api.barcodelookup.com/v2/products?barcode=" + passedBarcode + "&key=mj1pm32ylcctxj1byaia85n9dk2d4i";        
    const options = { method: 'GET' }; 

    currentComponent.setState({ barcode: passedBarcode });

    fetch( url, options)
    .then(function(response) {
        return response.json();
    })
    .then(function(myJson) {
        if (myJson == undefined) 
        {
            console.log("fetch failed")
        } 
        else 
        {     
            //inspect the data that the WebAPI returned
            var product_string = encodeURI(myJson.products[0].product_name);
            location.href="./ebaylookup?" + product_string + "&" + passedBarcode;
        }
    }); 
}

componentWillMount() {
    var barcodeParm = this.props.location.search.substring(1);
    this.barcodeLookup(barcodeParm);
}

manuallLookup() {        
    var manualBarCode = document.getElementById("manualBarcode").value;
    console.log("manual lookup: ", manualBarCode);
    this.barcodeLookup(manualBarCode);
}

render() {     

        return (
            <div>
                <div>
                    <label id="errorFont">Barcode {this.state.barcode} was not found by our barcode service.  You can re-scan your barcode or enter a barcode below</label>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <button className="btnStartScan"
                        type='button'     
                        onClick={() => { 
                            location.href = ('/newscan') 
                        }}>
                        Re-Scan
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <center><label className="appDescription">OR</label></center>
                </div>
                <div id="errorDivInput">
                    <center><input className="revisedProductName" id="manualBarcode"/></center><br />
                </div>
                <div>
                    <button className="btnStartScan" onClick={this.manuallLookup}>
                        Manually Lookup
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
}
}

export default Lookupbarcode;
```

The user has the option of clicking on a button which will route to a different page (/newscan) or manually enter a barcode into the input box.  If the user enters a bar code into the input box and clicks on the "Manually Lookup" button, I execute a function called manualLookup.

manualLookup should pick up the value of the barcode that the user entered and pass that value to the function barcodeLookup to see if the manually entered barcode is found in the barcode service.

When I execute the code, manually enter a bar code, and click on the Manually Lookup button, I get this error message in the console log:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'barcodeLookup' of undefined

The line that is causing the error is this:

> this.barcodeLookup(manualBarCode);

When I look in the console log, I see this which is generated in the manualLookup function:

```
manual lookup:  13131313131313131312
```

So, why am I unable to reference this.barcodeLookup() when I am able to reference it exactly the same way in the componentWillMount()?

Thanks for any assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to bind `manuallLookup` and `barcodeLookup` in the constructor. Doing so is necessary for any component methods that attempt to reference `this` inside of them.

So your constructor should look like:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);  
    this.state = {
        barcode: '',
    };
    this.barcodeLookup = this.barcodeLookup.bind(this);
    this.manuallLookup = this.manuallLookup.bind(this);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!